# Script is skipping the 'write the file' - part (PHP)

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

When I run this script, it works almost perfectly fine. It's setting this GPIO Pin on my Raspberry Pi high and echoes the `$inhalt2` variable 4 times (I did this to check if the script stucks somewhere). The problem is, it seems like it is skipping the part when it has to write the `$inhalt2` variable into the file. It doesn't show any errors, it simply doesn't write the file. What did I do wrong?

My PHP script looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["lighton"])){

    system ( "gpio write 1 1" );
    $inhalt2 = "light's on";
    echo $inhalt2;

    $handle = fopen ("light_status.txt", "w");
    echo $inhalt2;
    fwrite ($handle, "\n". $inhalt2);
    echo $inhalt2;
    fclose ($handle);
    echo $inhalt2;
}
```

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <h2>Light Control</h2>
    <h1></h1>
    <p>Licht</p>
    <input type="Submit" name="lighton" value="Light On" class="Light" href="index.php"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: you forgot to close the form? ;-/  `var_dump(is_writable(__DIR__))` ?  `it simply doesn't write the file` This means no file was created?

Comment: Oh I actually closed the form,  but I haven't copied it in here. But what do you mean with "var_dump(is_writable(__DIR__))"?

Comment: its `__DIR__` not `DIR` which is a predefined constant in PHP for the current directory.   As you have no path  in your filename I have to assume it goes into the current directory, and is_writable checks that you have write permission to a path.  (`__DIR__`, might be the working directory which is slightly different, I forget).  In otherwords you can create files in that location, correct?

Comment: ok. When I add that to my code, it says "testbool(false)". I assume it means that it has no permission. How do give it permission? Because I actually already gave it permission using the chmod 755 command. Is that the "wrong" permission?

Comment: Permission settings I cant really help you with as I don't know anything about this `Raspberry Pi ` I heard of it once on facebook.. lol, I was going to say too you may want to just do  `echo __DIR__;` to make sure it's the right path.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway

Comment: did you check the path, was that at least what it should be?

Comment: yes it was the right path